# Probability modeling : time series probability?

Tags: stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, time-series

I am a newbie researcher.

I have a question about probability modeling of time series.

For example, there is a time series such as,

10 8 2 9 1 2 4 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7...

**In above example, I want to express the probability that
sample is larger than 8.**

Assuming X(n) is time series, or discrete time stochastic process,

"P(X(n) > 8)" seems to be incorrect because X(n) is the set of random variables.

If X(n) is iid process, "P(X(n) > 8)" is correct.

**But, How could I express the probability when X(n) is identically distributed but not independent discrete time stochastic process?**

If you could help me, I'd appreciate it, really really.

Comment: The probability that *which* sample is larger than $8$? Is $X(n)$ the $n$-th sample of the process? In that case $P(X(n) > 8)$ is the probability that the $n$-th sample is larger than $8$. Or is $X(n)$ an entire process? If the j-th sample of this process is called $X(n)_j$, you'd use $P(X(n)_j > 8)$.

Comment: make assumptions, like the markov assumption.

Comment: @Magma I appreciate you. Yes I want to express the ratio, the number of samples larger than 8, over the entire process(the entire time slots). If the entire process samples are 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10,  "P(X(n)j>8) = 0.2". is it right? I appreciate you again.

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan Really thank you for your reply. the markov assumption? I know a little thing about Markov chain and Markov process, but could you give me a more explanation?

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan Suddenly I understand your words. Making a Markov process(,or chain) have states that I want to do will be a good solution. Really thanks!